# Python : How to interpolate the missing rates and plot the interpolated curve to compare the original curve?

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

```
data = {'tenor_yrs': [.1, .2, .3, .5, 1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30,40,50], 'rates': [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 2.01, 3, 1.99, 2.05, 3.19, 1.99, 3.16, 2.54, 3.5, 2.79]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Please suggest how to interpolate the missing years rates in python to build this curve with linear interpolation and plot the same. The number in decimals in tenor are months.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `tenor_years` as the index, `reindex` and `interpolate` to fill the missing values with a linear interpolation:

```
(df.set_index('tenor_yrs')
   .reindex(range(int(df.tenor_yrs.max())))
   .interpolate()
   .reset_index())

   tenor_yrs  rates
0          0    NaN
1          1  2.010
2          2  2.505
3          3  3.000
4          4  2.495
5          5  1.990
6          6  1.990
7          7  1.990
8          8  1.990
...
```

---

Update -

To include decimal places as steps, use:

```
start = int(df.tenor_yrs.min())
end = int(df.tenor_yrs.max())
step = df.loc[df.tenor_yrs>0, 'tenor_yrs'].min()

import numpy as np

(df.set_index('tenor_yrs')
   .reindex(np.arange(start, end, step))
   .interpolate()
   .reset_index())
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. This method seems linear(). Do we also also have cubic method to interpolate ?

Comment: you have reset the tenor as index but the tenor is till 50 yrs. Your output is giving the rates till 20 yrs. How to get rates till 50 yrs.

Comment: Updated @akash . As per the first question, here are the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html

Comment: Thanks. Am looking into it. Will come back soon. Thanks yatu.

Comment: Sure I will do that. One last question. Why its not producing the rates of months tenor which are in decimals ?

Comment: Check the update @akash (this is why you have to include the expected output always to avoid confusion)